# Get list of scheduled jobs by name/type

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

I wrote schedulable class which is a batch at the same time. I'm scheduling it like so:

```
String cronExpression = String.format('0 {0} {1} * * ?', new List<String> { String.valueOf(minute), String.valueOf(hour) });
String jobName = 'roomSyncronizationJob' + Integer.valueOf(hour);
return System.schedule(jobName, cronExpression, batch);
```

Then I have a page to display form for scheduling and table that should display scheduled jobs. For the moment, it displays all scheduled jobs in the system.

My question: **Is there any way to get the jobName to be able to filter out jobs that was not scheduled by the code above?** Does anybody know any other workaround except for storing all scheduled job ids in the database?

Answer (score 1):

There is one standard object "CronTrigger". May be this object will help you to get name.

Comment: CronTrigger object does NOT contain the field that I need. That's why I am asking this question, actually (

Answer (score 1):

Old, but i was searching for this.  CronTrigger contains the field CronJobDetailId.  CronJobDetail has the field "Name"